# How to draw into a bitmap and blit it on to the screen using Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bitmap

I am new to Objective C.
I am trying to draw(basic lines as of now) onto a bitmap and then have the bitmap rendered on the screen for Iphone.

Following is the code which i tried, it shows me nothing but a blank screen:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

CGContextRef screen = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
size_t width = rect.size.width;

size_t height = rect.size.height;

void *data = malloc(width*height*4); 

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef c = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}; // setting the color in CMYK format

CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);

CGContextBeginPath(c);

CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 5.0f, 5.0f);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 100.0f, 60.0f);

CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 100.0f, 100.0f);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 50.0f, 150.0f);

CGContextStrokePath(c);

CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(c);

CFRelease(c);

free(data);

CGContextDrawImage(screen, rect, img);

CGContextFlush(screen);

CGContextFlush(c);

CFRelease(colorSpace);

CGImageRelease(img);

CFRelease(screen);  
}
```

Let me know if anyone can point out a similar example or suggest changes to my code.

---

Thanks for the help everybody...
The code works but not as expected.

I modified the code as follows:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(screen, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //code works without these 3 lines
CGContextFillRect(screen, rect);
CGContextDrawImage(screen, rect, img);
```

But there is something weird happening, i can see black lines drawn when the color provided by me is green.
Here is the code after creating the bitmap context:

```
CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f}; //RGB values
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);
```

This seems to be the only combination for which the code works...

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you may be aware, but you're doing an extra step here. Although conceptually this approach will work, the `drawRect:` gets an implicit graphics context (which you know how to get with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`) and you can draw directly into that. There's no need to create the bitmap context and then blit it into the local context afterwards.

That said, your code generally looks reasonable. You're drawing in black without clearing the background to anything else, however, which might explain the all-black result. (The underlying bitmap is just the uninitialized memory from malloc unless you do an explicit clear or fill on it.) Try doing a rect fill on the whole context to white, or etc.

A few other notes:

1. You're setting the stroke color in RGBA, not CMYK per your comment, but your result is what you want.
2. Don't release the "screen" context-- you don't own that, since you didn't get it via a "create" method.
3. I don't think the flushes are required here, but even if they are, you're flushing "c" after you release it-- make sure you do it before if you want to.
4. You're drawing only inside the `rect` rectangle. This might be fine in your code, but note that this param can be any sub-rect of your view's bounds. If your intention is to blit the image into the whole view, you should ignore the `rect` param and just use `[self bounds]` as the drawing rectangle.

Comment: Hi Quixoto,

I am able to draw just by using the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext, but i wish to do it on a bitmap and the render it.

The Background is white by default, i can see a blank white screen, so i believe i dont need to do a rect fill on the whole context.

I think the code:
CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(c);
should get the drawings on the context c to the CGImageRef img, but i guess thats what is not happening.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know any other way or have an example for iphone bitmap drawing?

Comment: @Nisarg: Please see all of my comments. Your approach should be fine, but there are several other considerations. Your bitmap context is garbage data unless/until you clear/fill it. Something else is probably causing you not to see that.

Comment: @Nisarg: Again, the color is RGB, not CMYK. So you're now providing pure green with full transparency, which isn't helpful. You want some opacity to see it. Also, you need to clear the *bitmap* context that you are creating, not the actual view context, which UIKit will clear for you.

Comment: @quixoto: oh yes i realize that its RGB, sorry about that.
Now i am more confused... i see a black line with following code:
    CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(screen, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

Comment: @quixoto: The code works without using CGContextFillRect. I can see black lines only for the RGB values  CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
This is so weird....

Comment: Flushing is required depending on which backing the window was created with.

Answer (score 0):

Is this drawRect code actually getting called?  (Did you do a setNeedsDisplay somewhere else?)

What values is drawRect getting for width and height?  Does your drawing fit inside those coordinates?

Also, you may be drawing a black line to an initially black (0,0,0) bitmap.  Try a different color (red, for instance).

You can also dump the bytes of your bitmap data to a file and see how they are initialized, and if they are getting changed by your drawing commands.

ADDED:

Try using the iOS API for setting your colors:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // RGBA
```

Comment: yes changing color values helped... but its not what i expected... kindly refer to my latest post... Thanks